# Grails 3.3.9 : Could not resolve view with name '', when view is in project structure

Tags: grails, deployment, view, grails-3.3

I am running Grails 3.3.9. I created a small app to measure application usage. I am able to run my project locally without any issues, however when deploying as a war file, I run into the following error on all requested actions, even though the views are present.

```
Forwarding to error page from request [/q/action_name] due to exception [Could not resolve view with name 'action_name' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet']
```

Could it be that my controller name is too short? Its a letter.

Any guidance would be most appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add more details about how you're creating the war and how you're running the war (deploying to container, etc?)

Comment: Thanks but figured it out. It had to do with my controller naming. In creating a quick prototype I created the problem. You cannot use letters like AController or BController.

Comment: It may be worth opening an issue in grails-core with this - I see the same thing - works in dev mode but not in a compiled war/jar.

Comment: Ok, I might do that. Thanks!

Comment: I have the same issue, unable to find the view.. but in my case the Controller name is not the problem.. the view is in plugin. And i am doing gradle bootRun